# WebRTC Data Channel is always in connecting state

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am trying to send JSON/Text data through a peer connection using WEBRTC. But my `datachannel` is always stuck in the `connecting` state and I think that is an issue cause my text messages are not sent to the connected peer.

JS CODE (Client Side):

```
 let ws;
        let rtcPeerConnection;
        let dataChannel;

        const chatBox = document.getElementById('chatBox');
        const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
        const sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');

        sendButton.onclick = sendMessage;

        function sendMessage() {
            const message = messageInput.value;
            if (message.trim() !== '') {
                chatBox.value += `You: ${message}\n`;
                sendData(message);
                messageInput.value = '';
            }
        }

        function receiveMessage(message) {
            chatBox.value += `Peer: ${message}\n`;
        }

        function sendData(data) {
            console.log(dataChannel.readyState) //this always logs connecting
            if (dataChannel && dataChannel.readyState === 'open') {
                dataChannel.send(data);
            }
        }

        function init() {
            ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
            ws.onmessage = event => receiveMessage(event.data);

            rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
            rtcPeerConnection.ondatachannel = event => {
                dataChannel = event.channel;
                dataChannel.onmessage = event => receiveMessage(event.data);
            };

            const dataChannelOptions = { ordered: true };
            dataChannel = rtcPeerConnection.createDataChannel('textChat', dataChannelOptions);

            rtcPeerConnection.createOffer()
                .then(offer => rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
                .then(() => {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'offer',
                        data: rtcPeerConnection.localDescription
                    }));
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error creating offer:', error));

            ws.onmessage = async event => {
                const message = JSON.parse(event.data.toString());
                if (message.type === 'answer') {
                    await rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(message.data);
                } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
                    await rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(message.data);
                    const answer = await rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer();
                    await rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'answer',
                        data: rtcPeerConnection.localDescription
                    }));
                }
            };
        }

        init();
```

For the Signaling Server I am using Node Js Websockets below is the basic code for the server.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', message => {
        wss.clients.forEach(client => {
            if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(message.toString());
            }
        });
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I am not sure where is the issue in my code. please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exchanging ICE candidates, i.e. IP addresses where the peers can connect. See the [webrtc sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/basic/) and look for the onicecandidate handler and the addIceCandidate calls.

Comment: can you please provide a simple example on exchanging ICE candidates?